# JavaScript CJT using a Combobox to change picture

Tags: javascript, image, combobox, wordpress

Im new to using java script and im using the CJT plugin for wordpress. Ive been trying to make a picture change when a different value is selected in a combo box but i am having trouble getting it to work. Im not sure where im going wrong and would like someone to explain what im doing wrong. The code that i have is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var pictureList = [
    "(url)/image1.png",
    "(url)/image2.png",
    "(url)/image3.png",
    "(url)/image4.png",
    "(url)/image5.png", ];

$('#imagePic').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#imagePic').val());
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
});
</script>

<img src="(url)/image1.png" />
<select id="imagePic">
    <option value="image1" selected>Picture 1</option>
    <option value="image2">Picture 2</option>
    <option value="image3">Picture 3</option>
    <option value="image4">Picture 4</option>
    <option value="image5">Picture 5</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

(url) is the correct url for the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var pictureList = [
    "(url)/image1.png",
    "(url)/image2.png",
    "(url)/image3.png",
    "(url)/image4.png",
    "(url)/image5.png"
];

$('#imagePic').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find( ':selected' ).index();
    $('img').attr( "src", pictureList[index] );
});
```

That way you'll get the index of selected option. Also, remove the comma after the last item in the array.

Comment: Ive tried this method but the images still dont change depending on the selection of the combo box. The image just remains as the default image.

Comment: Put the script after the select box, you should also wrap it inside [domready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event `jQuery( function ($) { /* put javascript code here */ });`

Comment: It was the plugin i was using it works now :) thanks for the help!